# How do I fix "make: No rule to make target `config'"?

Tags: make

When I type `make config` in the terminal, the system responds with:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `config'.  Stop.
```

Any idea how to fix that problem?

Comment: @MichaelKjorling Do you want to update the description, as it is a little messy towards the end of the code?

Comment: @Kevdog777 Better now? (Next time, you can do it yourself; even if you don't have the rep to make immediate edits, you can always suggest them.)

Comment: It wouldn't let me, it needed to be more than 6 edits - but that is better, thanks :)

Comment: Are you compiling a package?

Comment: What are you trying to do? This command only makes sense if there is a makefile in the current directory containing a rule to build the target `config`. Why were you expecting it to work?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you were doing when you got that error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't run `make config` just anywhere - You have to be in a directory which contains a Make file. To verify:

```
ls Makefile
```

This file has to contain a target called `config`:

```
grep ^config Makefile
```

(this last command will not match *all* possible Makefile syntax, but if it's a simple file it should at least show you if there is another target like `configure` or `configuration`.)

Answer (score 1):

It means that `make` doesn't know what to do with the `config` argument. It does not exist. Read the `Makefile` to determine what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Software configuration on *nix is usually made by running the `configure` script in the project top-level directory:

```
cd /path/to/project
./configure
```

Have you tried that?

Comment: You mean I have to find the ./configure or what?