# How to fix "cannot access 'Makefile': No such file or directory"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configuration

I am trying to config the default kernel:

`$ mkdir ˜/kernelbuild`

`$ cd ˜/kernelbuild`

`$ wget https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/linux -5.0.5.tar.xz`

`$ tar -xvJf linux -5.0.5.tar.xz`

`$ cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) ˜/kernelbuild/.config`

`$ sudo apt-get install fakeroot ncurses-dev xz-utils bc flex libelf-dev bison`

Then

`$ make nconfig`

and get error

> "cannot access 'Makefile': No such file or directory"

Have read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103080/how-do-i-fix-make-no-rule-to-make-target-config). And I got:

[image: ls Makefile]

Any suggestion to what I'm gonna do next?

Comment: you look inside the directory that came from the tarball. Also, [please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), esp. that blue on black is somewhat hard to read. (even if it is used by default in some Linux distributions.)

Comment: The kernel archive unpacked into its own subdirectory. You can see this directory in the output of `ls`. The Makefile is in there along with all the kernel source.

Answer (score 2):

There is no Makefile in `˜/kernelbuild`, you need to change directory to `˜/kernelbuild/linux -5.0.5`:

```
cd ˜/kernelbuild/linux -5.0.5
make nconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$ make` with out nconfig.
I see you are trying to compile kernel, for my self i found this link helpful:
https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/how-compile-linux-kernel-0/